# C sorting changes the value in array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Hi I am using a sorting algorithm in one of my program. It is quick sort. I tested it with a sorted array as follow

```
int arr[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

Code of sorting algorithm is

```
void sort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
   int i= left, j= right;
   int pivot = arr[((left+right)/2)];
   int tmp=0;


/* partition */
   printf("%d\n",arr[0]);
   while(i<=j)
   {
      while(arr[i]<pivot)
          i++;

      while(arr[j]>pivot)
          j--;

      if(i<=j)
      {
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
      }


   };

/* recursion */

   if(left<j)
      sort(arr,left,j);
   if(i<right)
      sort(arr,i,right);

 }
```

When it return the result it gives arr[0] value as 0. which should be 1.

I am calling this function inside main. Below is the code for calling sort

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  int arr[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};int max=0,min=0;

  int len = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

  printf("%d\n",arr[0]);

  sort(arr,0,len);

  printf("%d\n",arr[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you include where `sort()` is called and what the values of `left` and `right` are?

Comment: I edited the question and added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
sort(arr,0,len);
```

You're passing the size as the rightmost array element.  This results in you reading and writing off the end of the array, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to pass in the index of the rightmost element, which is 1 less:

```
sort(arr,0,len-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm itself looks good, except I think it's better to have `<= pivot` and `>= pivot` in the `while` loops.

The only issue I can think about is that you call the `sort` function with arguments `0` and number of elements in the array. But note the `right` here means the index of the right position, not behind. So it should be `7` or `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])-1)`